# Factorization and roots of a multivariate polynomial over finite fields

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields, factoring, irreducible-polynomials, multivariate-polynomial

I am interested to know whether factorization of a multivariate polynomial $f(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n) \in \mathbb{F}_p[x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n]$ into irreducible factors yields some information about the roots of $f(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n)$.

For instance, for the univariate polynomials we know that if $f(x) = (x-a)(x-b) = 0$, then $x=a, x=b$ are the roots of the polynomial $f(x)$. Is there a similar relation between the irreducible factors of a multivariate polynomial $f(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n)$ in $\mathbb{F}_p[x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n]$ and its roots? I would really appreciate any literature suggestions on this topic as well, thank you!

Comment: What type of information are you looking for? If $f(x,y)=(x-y^2)(x^2-y)$ then the factors are surely irreducible, and we can deduce that $f(a,b)=0$ if and only if either $a=b^2$ or $b=a^2$ (or both). When you further look for factorizations over the algebraic closure, so in $\overline{\Bbb{F}_p}[x,y]$, you get so called *absolutely irreducible* polynomials. Those define curves. Studying them quickly takes you into *algebraic geometry.*

Comment: I mean, it's not like you get one zero per irreducible factor like in the univariate case (assuming a splitting field).

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the direction of algebraic geometry. Yes, I completely agree that we get more than one zero per irreducible factor. I am, in general, interested in finding roots of multivariate polynomials over finite fields but there aren't as many efficient algorithms to do that for a large field or large number of variables and degrees of polynomials. However, I saw some efficient algorithms to factor multivariate polynomials and I was hoping I can get something from there.

Comment: For instance, in the example that you gave if I know that we need $a=b^2$ and/or $b=a^2$ and if I am just doing brute force, I will have a much smaller set of possibilities in this case rather than going through the entire field. Of course, this is still a lot of work.